# Using a lemon's energy

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electricity

Some simple exercises i need some confirmations on.

Let's say a lemon has U = 1V and an average current of 0.1mA for about an hour.

Q1. How much lemons do you need to light a 100W bulb.
Is the answer 1 million lemons ?

Q2.The Atmega1284P processor has an average energy consumption of 0.18nJ/instruction. How much instructions can be executed from a single lemon.
Is the answer (6*10^6)/0.18 ?

And a bonus one i haven't figured :

A battery that functions at 1Ah is draining with 4C on a resistance of 2W. How much time till the battery is fully drained.

Comment: How come resistance appears measured in watts?

Comment: That's how i found it and the same thing I was confused about it. Thought i'm missing something .

Comment: What would the answer be if we were to exclude that part of the question, or at least switch it to a proper resistance measurement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $P=UI$, for Q1 $100W=1V\cdot 0.1mA\cdot N\Rightarrow N=10^6$, so your answer is right.

For single lemon we have $A=1V\cdot 0.1mA\cdot 3600 s=360mJ$. Thus we can execute $A/q=360mJ/(0.18nJ/instruction)=2\cdot 10^9$ instructions.

Comment: Yea , i got it wrong by converting 1 hour into 60 seconds instead of 3600 xD. Thank you. As with the battery question, it turns out it is the Power = 2 W through a resistance. So 1Ah = 3600 coulombs. T(draining time) = 3600/P => 1800 seconds ? 30 minutes